# Ubuntu covert all images in a folder

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick-convert

I am using a script for converting all the images in my folder to flop operation. The script is like this:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    new="${f%%.jpg}_flop.jpg";
    convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new";
 done
```

Now I have found that there may be also images with the extension `.JPG` I thought of adding a new for loop that looks like this:

```
for f in *.JPG; do
    new="${f%%.jpg}_flop.jpg";
    convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new";
 done
```

I think that there is a syntax for ignoring the case, and this way I can do a single loop instead of 2, any help?

More, if there will also be the extensions `.jpeg` or `.JPEG`, is there a syntax for this, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
for f in *.jpg *.JPG; do
    ...
```

If you want a single expression, you can use the [`extglob`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC38) extension in Bash.

```
set -o extglob
for f in *.@(JP@(|E)G|jp@(|e)g); do
    ...
```

To make globbing case insensitive, you can [`shopt -s nocaseglob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) but there is no particular syntax to make a single glob expression case-insensitive.

You could also use the slightly imprecise

```
for f in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] *.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]; do
    ...
```

to match case-insensitively.

Comment: Last option works, but: 1. I have some problems with the extension: If the ext is not the one mentioned after `new="${f%%.here}_flop.jpg";` It is converting to the file file.here_flop.jpg. 2. set -o extglob and shopt does not work for my case, I do not know why (any suggestions?). 3. If I have no files with an ext (like .jpeg) it prints some error, but it does the conversion for the other files

Comment: I can speculate that you are using `#!/bin/sh` on the shebang line, which runs a different shell, or (on some installations) Bash with all Bash-specific extensions disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
#/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob                # don't give error messages if no matching files
shopt -s nocaseglob              # ignore case
for f in *.jpg *.jpeg; do

   new=${f/.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]/}      # strip extension
   new=${new/.[Jj][Pp][Gg]/}        # whether JPEG or jpg
   new="$new_flop.jpg"

   convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new"
done
```

Comment: `flop_all_images.sh: 1: flop_all_images.sh: shopt: not found
flop_all_images.sh: 2: flop_all_images.sh: shopt: not found
flop_all_images.sh: 4: flop_all_images.sh: Bad substitution`
How to enable shopt ?

Comment: Sorry, it is a bash-ism. You need `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.

Comment: I've added it, but still saying the `shopt: not found`. And still `Bad substitution`.

Comment: Try making the first line `#!/bin/bash -xv` and running it again to debug

Comment: Try `which bash` and `bash -version`

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I am running the code you have posted (copy paste) and I am getting the 3 lines of errors: `shopt: not found` and `Bad substitution` (the ones that I have posted in the first comment)

Comment: Bad substitution is here: `new=${f/.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]/}`

Comment: I have no idea what is going on! Maybe you can paste following into your shell and experiment till you find the syntax your `bash` understands.... `f=abc.jpEg; new=${f/[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]/fred}; echo $new` It should say `abc.fred` whatever you do with the `JPEG|jpg` part.

Comment: Interesting: if I post it in the script, then I get the bad substitution error, and if I just type it in terminal, it does what you expect.

Comment: I am assuming you saved my script in a file as, say `go`, then did `chmod +x go` followed by `./go`

Comment: yes, `flop_all_images.sh`, then `chmod +x flop_all_images.sh` then `./flop_all_images.sh`. How would you suggest me to do instead of this?

Comment: That is the correct approach already, I was worried you were just pasting the whole script into the shell, but it is ok, you are not. I can only speculate, like @tripleee that you are somehow not using  normal `bash`.

Comment: Maybe one of my heroes, @anubhava will have a moment and be able to take a look and suggest something...

Comment: by the way, which bash is printing `/bin/bash`

Comment: Try `ls -l /bin/bash` to see if it symlinked to `sh` or something.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1021112 sept. 27 10:04 /bin/bash` what does this means? :)

Comment: It means your `bash` is not symbolically linked to some other shell such as `fish` or `sh`, so that is not the cause of the problems either.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that does something similar:

```
for file in {*.jpg,*.JPG}; do
  mv "$file" "old$file"
  convert -resize 3000000@\> "old$file" -quality 80 "$file"
  rm "old$file"
done
```

I also made a video explaining it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG0bItQLBdI

Comment: `{*.jpg,*.JPG}` makes the echo to print `convert *.jpg, to *.jpg,_flop.jpg` (etc)

Comment: it's a script, see other comments. The command looked like `for file in {*.jpg,*.JPG}; do new="${f%%.jpg}_flop.jpg"; convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new"; done`, but i have changed it to `for f in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] *.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]; do new="${f%%.[Jj][Pp][Gg]}_flop.jpg"; convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new"; done` and I just get just the errors of no such an extension kind.

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in `ls * | grep -i "jp[e]\?g$"`;do
   new="${f%%.jpg}_flop.jpg";     
   echo convert "$f" -flop -quality 100 "$new";  
done
```

Regular expressions are your friend.

Comment: I lost the backticks first time round

Comment: That is an interesting article, I suppose we do have to guard against insane file names.