# Ubuntu script to rename all images in folder

Tags: ubuntu, sh, dash-shell

I am using the following code to rename all the images in the current folder:

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a}); #04 pad to length of 4
  mv ${i} ${new};
  a=$((a+1));
done
```

But I have met a problem: some of the images were overwritten, because I use it after I have added more images in the folder. Is there a way to fix this? I thought to add an `if (name_exists) then next_name`, but I am new to scripts. Any help, please?

Comment: `-n` option for no-clobber?

Comment: If you just want to get the job done, create a sub-directory in current directory, `mv ${i} tmpdir/${new}` & then move all the .jpg files from tmpdir to current directory. (Assuming that there will not be new files getting added in current directiory, while operation is going on.

Comment: What does it happen if I use the -n flag? Does it nor rename the current file or it does increment a until it finds a possible name?

Comment: With the `-n` option, the renaming will just fail, and the file is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
glob="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"
last=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$glob" -print |sort -gr |grep -Pom1 '\d{4}') # or  |grep -om1 '[0-9][0-9]*')
last=${last:-0}
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r image
do
    let last++
    echo mv "$image" "$(printf "%04s" $last ).jpg"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.jpg -a -not -name "$glob" -print0)
```

where:

- 1st `find` finds the last used number
- the `while read` reads the output from the
- 2nd `find` what finds all `.jpg` what have different name as NNNN.jpg
- increment and rename

You can imprpve this

- search other types of images (not only jpg)
- change the script to case insensitive
- the above will fail if the image count raises above `9999`... so...

The script is in *dry* mode, remove the `echo` when satisfied

### EDIT

dash version:

```
glob="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"
last=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$glob" -print |sort -gr |grep -Pom1 '\d{4}') # or  |grep -om1 '[0-9][0-9]*')
last=${last:-0}
for image in *.jpg
do
    echo "$image" | grep -q "^$glob$" && continue
    #last=$((last+1))  #with leading zeroes, the numbers treated as octal... fails for 08 and such
    last=$(expr $last + 1)
    echo mv "$image" "$(printf "%04d" $last ).jpg"
done
```

Comment: Why do I get `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`?

Comment: Still the same error, I think that it is something about my bash, because I had strange error when trying something else (see [these comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26213144/3062311))

Comment: @sop you don't using `bash` but `dash`. If you want `dash` script, don't tag your question as `bash`... The default shell in ubuntu is `dash` not `bash`... omg.. ;( The `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` is an `dash's` error message.

Comment: Thanks for idea. How to do it in dash? :)

Comment: How to fix this: `7: Illegal number: 0018`? Is it possible to keep the 0s in front?

Comment: @sop - if you not edited the script - e.g. copy it EXACTLY, you can't have spaces in the destination filename, the `"$(printf "%04d" $last ).jpg"` create a filename **without** any space.

Comment: And it renames only the files that have not the wanted format?

Comment: @sop - yes. but, please test it yourself. If not doing what you want, leave it - if doing what you want accept it.. ;) The minimal understanding what the script does is needed...

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your script

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do
    new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a});
    while [ -f ${new} ]
    do
       a=$((a+1));
       new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a});
    done
    mv ${i} ${new};
    a=$((a+1));
done
```

if you are not too particular about the numbered names. You could use this:

```
if [ -f ${new} ]
then
    new=$(printf "%04d_%s.jpg" ${a} $(date +'%H_%M_%S'))
fi
```

instead of while.

Comment: I really like the idea of the date, like this I'll always have a `0001` image.

Comment: This will rename the existing `0001.jpg` to the next avaliable number such `0111.jpg`. The `for` get `0001.jpg` the `while` will search for the next available number and rename it...